# Error 1005: Can't create table can't find where the problem is

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have created a EER model using MySQL Workbench (latest release). Apparently all is fine but when I try to do a FORWARD ENGINEER I get the common **Error 1005: Can't create table**. As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150) I check every step on the first answer but without success, can any give some extra eyes to my query and try to find where my error is? I can't see it.

This is the error generated by the tool:

```
Executing SQL script in server
```

> ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table
>   'portal_de_logistica.order_has_comment' (errno: 150)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_order` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `comment` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `no_order`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fos_user_rnd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tb_order_rnd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`no_order`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
```

And this is the complete SQL sentences:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `portal_de_logistica` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`company`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`company` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`company` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `register_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `country` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`contact`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`contact` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`contact` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  `c_position` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_company1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`company` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_contact_company1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`contact` (`company_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (
  `no_order` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `business_case` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `charge_status` ENUM('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8') NOT NULL COMMENT '0: Ninguno\n1: Proceso de Fabricacion\n2: Pickup en destino\n3: A la espera de recojo por cliente\n4: Carga en transito\n5: Carga arribada\n6: En proceso de aduana\n7: Entregado a cliente\n8: En bodega',
  `eta` DATE NULL,
  `etd` DATE NULL,
  `transport_media` ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL COMMENT '0: EXW\n1: Maritimo' /* comment truncated */ /*2: Aereo*/,
  `incoterm` ENUM('0','1','2','3','4') NULL COMMENT '0: Ninguno\n1: EWX\n2: FOB\n3: CIF' /* comment truncated */ /*4: DDP*/,
  PRIMARY KEY (`no_order`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_company1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`company` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `no_order_UNIQUE` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_order_company1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`company_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `roles` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_583D1F3E5E237E06` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group` (`name` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `username_canonical` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `email_canonical` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `salt` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `last_login` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `expired` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `expires_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmation_token` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_requested_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `roles` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `credentials_expired` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `credentials_expire_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `biography` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `locale` VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_uid` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_data` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)',
  `twitter_uid` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_data` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)',
  `gplus_uid` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gplus_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gplus_data` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)',
  `token` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `two_step_code` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_C560D76192FC23A8` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`username_canonical` ASC);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_C560D761A0D96FBF` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`email_canonical` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B3C77447FE54D947`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B3C77447A76ED395`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX `IDX_B3C77447A76ED395` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group` (`user_id` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `IDX_B3C77447FE54D947` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group` (`group_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `context` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `default_format` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `provider_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `provider_status` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `provider_reference` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `provider_metadata` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)',
  `width` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `content_type` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `content_size` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `copyright` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `context` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cdn_is_flushable` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cdn_flush_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cdn_status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gallery_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_80D4C541EA9FDD75`
    FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_80D4C5414E7AF8F`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gallery_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX `IDX_80D4C5414E7AF8F` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media` (`gallery_id` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `IDX_80D4C541EA9FDD75` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media` (`media_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company` (
  `fos_user_user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fos_user_user_id`, `company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fos_user_user_has_company_fos_user_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fos_user_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fos_user_user_has_company_company1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`company` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX `fk_fos_user_user_has_company_company1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company` (`company_id` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_fos_user_user_has_company_fos_user_user1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company` (`fos_user_user_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media` (
  `order_no_order` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `media__media_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_no_order`, `media__media_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_has_media__media_order1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`order_no_order`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_has_media__media_media__media1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`media__media_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_order_has_media__media_media__media1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media` (`media__media_id` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_order_has_media__media_order1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media` (`order_no_order` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_order` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `comment` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `no_order`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fos_user_rnd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tb_order_rnd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`no_order`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX `fk_fos_user_user_has_tb_order_tb_order1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` (`no_order` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_fos_user_user_has_tb_order_fos_user_user1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` (`user_id` ASC);


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

**EDIT: Add more info**

Following @Up_One answer I run the command and get this as output:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
140225  3:51:56 Error in foreign key constraint of table portal_de_logistica/order_has_comment:

    FOREIGN KEY (`no_order`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

Comment: You don't have `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci` in all the tables.

Comment: So you skipped step 6 from that link: *"6. Make sure that the Charset and Collate options are the same both at the table level as well as individual field level for the key columns."*

Comment: @ypercube is spot on - either add that to the definition of tb_order or consider changing the beginning of your script to `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS portal_de_logistica DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: @ypercube add the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE` in all  tables fix the problem, thanks all of yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This error is because of you innodb engine referenced constraint** 
read the article from this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150312170659/https://aodba.com/en/blog/2014/12/01/solution-error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-mysql/) - this will fix your problem

**Or you can read my answer on this page !**
Because of you referential integrity on **ENGINE = InnoDB**, you need to make sure that the referenced table must carry the same engine type.

To find out if this is your case use the command bellow :

```
SHOW engine innodb STATUS;
```

This command will list the dump log of your innodb engine.
, if this is your case make sure you fix the engine type by altering the table to carry the same engine when referencing one another! 
Example of out put :

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
1001111 13:11:00 Error IN FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT OF TABLE my_data :
FOREIGN KEY(id)
REFERENCES pk(test1):
Cannot find an INDEX IN the referenced TABLE WHERE the
referenced COLUMNS appear AS the FIRST COLUMNS, OR COLUMN types
IN the TABLE AND the referenced TABLE do NOT MATCH FOR CONSTRAINT.
```